# Error While Enabling TPM

Tags: command-line, wine, tpm

First thing's first, I opened up the terminal and entered `sudo apt-get install tpm-tools trousers` and it asked if I was okay with it taking up 'x' amount of space but then as it installed, this error came up

```
Setting up trousers (0.3.14+fixed1-1) ...
Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-07-09 12:51:11 EDT; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9449 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)

Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n trousers[9449]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n tcsd[9454]: TCSD TDDL[9454]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) In…vice
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n tcsd[9454]: TCSD TDDL[9454]: TrouSerS Falling back t…ort.
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n trousers[9449]:    ...fail!
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited…s=30
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 12:51:11 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'ex…de'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package trousers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tpm-tools:
 tpm-tools depends on trousers; however:
  Package trousers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tpm-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 trousers
 tpm-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not exactly sure what to do. I just wanted to open a `.exe` file on Ubuntu and `Wine` was asking me to install TPM drivers.

Now the same error is happening for `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

Output of `sudo systemctl status trousers.service`:

```
● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-07-09 15:40:49 EDT; 58s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12970 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)

Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n trousers[12970]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcs
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n tcsd[12975]: TCSD TDDL[12975]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inapp
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n tcsd[12975]: TCSD TDDL[12975]: TrouSerS Falling back to R
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n trousers[12970]:    ...fail!
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited, cod
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 15:40:49 s3id0n systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
```

Comment: What EXE are you trying to run?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo systemctl status trousers.service`? Also, which program are you trying to run via Wine and what exactly was the messages (and source) that prompted you to install these packages?

Comment: @Wilf I'm trying to run Samsung Flow :)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm attempting to open Samsung Flow, and have added the output of that above :)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `sudo systemctl -l status trousers.service`. Also, it looks like Samsung Flow requires a kernel driver in Windows, which means that it's unlikely to run in Wine.

Comment: @DavidFoerster would it then not be able to run on linux at all?

Comment: Wine doesn't have a concept of or programming interfaces for kernel drivers. It relies on existing operating system services of a previously known type (graphics display, human interface devices, file systems, network interfaces, audio devices, printers etc.) but can't add or install new services. (Kernel drivers are one way to provide operating system services.)